# TypeError: L.Proj is undefined in leaflet

Tags: wms, leaflet, error

I am using leaflet 0.7.3. I am trying to load a wms tile:

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2236', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=24.33333333333333 +lon_0=-81 +k=0.999941177 +x_0=200000.0001016002 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs',
{
    resolutions: [8192, 4096, 2048],
});

// pass crs into map constructor
var map = new L.map('map',
{
    crs: crs
});

...
```

But am getting an error:

> TypeError: L.Proj is undefined

Has anybody received this error, and if so, how did you resolve this issue?